consumer is not invoked when publishing from another one
I have an issue using kafka with spring boot, I have a spring boot microservice that is linked to kafka,this app works fine, I can produce and consume events with no problem excpet this cas :
I need to produce an event via a consumer so another microservice consume it, this is the consumer that produce the event :
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class TaskListener {
    private final TaskService taskService;
    private final KafkaConsumer<TaskEvent> taskConsumer;
    private final KafkaProducer<String, TaskEvent> producer;
    private final KafkaTopicProps kafkaTopicProps;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "v1-add-task", groupId = "add-task", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consumingAddTask(
            @Payload TaskEvent message,
            @Header(name = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
            @Header(name = KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) int offset) {
        log.debug("[START-ADD-TASK-CONSUMER] Message : {}, Partition: {}, Offset: {}", message, partition, offset);
        taskConsumer.listener(message, partition, offset, event -> {
            var task = taskService.addTask(event.getBody()); // simple call to jpa that works fine
            if(task != null && task.getId() != null) {
                event.setTaskId(task.getId());
                producer.send(kafkaTopicProps.taskTopic().getPushNotification(), null, event, null);// kafkaTopicProps.taskTopic().getPushNotification() = v1-push-notif
            }
        });
        log.debug("[END-ADD-TASK-CONSUMER] Message : {}, Partition: {}, Offset: {}", message, partition, offset);
    }
}


@Component
@Slf4j
public class ConsumerImpl<T extends Event> implements KafkaConsumer<T> {

    @Override
    public void listener(T event, int partition, int offset, Consumer<T> consume) {
        log.info("Start receiving message : Type {}, Partition: {}, Offset: {}", event.getActionType(), partition, offset);
        consume.accept(event);
        log.info("end receiving message : Type {}, Partition: {}, Offset: {}", event.getActionType(), partition, offset);
    }
}




@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProducerImpl<K, V> implements KafkaProducer<K, V> {
    private final KafkaTemplate<K, V> kafkaTemplate;

    @Override
    public Future<SendResult<K, V>> send(String topic, K key, V data, BiConsumer<K, V> callback) {
        log.info("Start sending message : Topic {}, Key: {}", topic, key);

        // Use CompletableFuture to run kafkaTemplate.send() asynchronously
        CompletableFuture<ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>>> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> key != null ? kafkaTemplate.send(topic, key, data) : kafkaTemplate.send(topic, data));

        // Attach a callback to be executed after the asynchronous operation completes
        future.thenAccept(sendResult -> {
            log.info("End sending message : Topic {}, Key: {}", topic, key);
            if (callback != null) {
                log.info("Executing callback logic after message sending");
                callback.accept(key, data);
            }
        });
        try {
            return future.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            log.error("having interruption error while extracting callback : {}", e.getMessage());
            throw new TechnicalException(e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            log.error("having execution error while extracting callback : {}", e.getMessage());
            throw new TechnicalException(e);
        }
    }
}



the producing logic works fine and I can see the event send to kafka.
on the other hand, the other microservice should consume  v1-push-notif :
@Component("ATNotificationListener")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class NotificationListener {
    private final KafkaConsumer<TaskEvent> taskConsumer;
    private final KafkaProducer<String, TaskEvent> producer;
    private final NotificationService notificationService;
    private final KafkaTopicProps kafkaTopicProps;
    private NotificationMapper notificationMapper = Mappers.getMapper(NotificationMapper.class);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "v1-push-notif", groupId = "update-at-notification-linked-to-task", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consumingPushNotificationLinkedToTask(
            @Payload TaskEvent message,
            @Header(name = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition,
            @Header(name = KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) int offset) {
        log.debug("[START-NOTIFICATION-PUSH-CONSUMER] Message : {}, Partition: {}, Offset: {}", message, partition, offset);
        taskConsumer.listener(message, partition, offset, event -> {
            var globalNotification = notificationMapper.mapToGlobalNotification(notificationMapper.mapTaskToNotification(event.getBody())); // mapping event to dto
            var notification = notificationService.pushNotification(globalNotification); // simple call to jpa
            if(notification != null && notification.getId() != null) {
                event.setNotificationId(notification.getId());
                producer.send(kafkaTopicProps.notificationAtTopic().getUpdateTask(), null, event, null);
            }
        });
        log.debug("[END-NOTIFICATION-PUSH-CONSUMER] Message : {}, Partition: {}, Offset: {}", message, partition, offset);
    }

}

the problem is that consumingPushNotificationLinkedToTask is not invoked even that v1-push-notif has events.
here is the kafka configuration class (the same for the two microservices) :
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties();
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);

        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory) {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    }

    /**
     * Configures a Kafka ConsumerFactory to deserialize Kafka messages with the specified properties.
     *
     * @param kafkaProperties KafkaProperties containing Kafka configuration properties.
     * @param objectMapper   ObjectMapper for deserializing JSON payloads.
     * @return Configured ConsumerFactory for deserializing Kafka messages.
     */
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Event> consumerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        // Build properties map from KafkaProperties
        Map<String, Object> props = kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties();

        // Configure deserializers for keys and values
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);

        // Configure ErrorHandlingDeserializer to use JsonDeserializer for value deserialization
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class);

        // Create JsonDeserializer instance for deserializing values with type information from headers
        var jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(Event.class, objectMapper, true);

        // Add trusted packages to JsonDeserializer to allow deserialization of specific package(s)
        jsonDeserializer.addTrustedPackages("com.pj.notification.event");

        // Return configured ConsumerFactory with StringDeserializer for keys and JsonDeserializer for values
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), jsonDeserializer);
    }




    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, Event>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConsumerFactory<String, Event> consumerFactory) {
        var factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Event>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        factory.setRecordInterceptor(new KafkaConsumerInterceptor<>());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAuthExceptionRetryInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(7));
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new KafkaErrorHandler());
        return factory;
    }
}



@Bean
ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties();
    configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);

    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean
KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory) {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
}

/**
 * Configures a Kafka ConsumerFactory to deserialize Kafka messages with the specified properties.
 *
 * @param kafkaProperties KafkaProperties containing Kafka configuration properties.
 * @param objectMapper   ObjectMapper for deserializing JSON payloads.
 * @return Configured ConsumerFactory


omments are used to ask for clarificati

Kindly add how this answer is useful
